# Date range selection globally or per screen?

Tags: user-interface, user-controls

I need some advice about the design on my app.

I have several screens where I need a date range to show content. One has rows of text data and others are charts. All but one need future dates (one needs dates in the past).

I have a screen where they can select the date range and a quick way to select 30 days etc.

I think I have two options. 1) allow one date range to be used though-out all screens (apart from that one chart). 2) allow a date range to be selected for each.

However, both of these have issues, I may have to correct old dates and theres that one chart. Although, making these corrections could cause confusion.

My main issue, is that I don't want to confuse my users.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend placing a date range selector on each screen.  It makes the content super obvious and a little easier to use.  For convenience, you could have previously selected date ranges persist between screens for users who want all the data for the same dates.

**edit:** What is the platform?  If its a mobile phone I would recommend a separate screen for the date range and if it is a computer I would recommend the date range selector on each screen.

Comment: At the moment, on my charts I have `Title of chart - from date to date` which I don't think is that obvious. Also, I'd need to make corrections, this could be confusing ?

Comment: Corrections can definitely be confusing for someone who didn't create the program.  I have noticed that when I am making something I can clearly imagine how I would use it, but not a user who was not involved in the creation process.  My best example is when I made a form for a small accounting application.  I imagined users using 'tab' to go through the inputs but when I showed it to my test user he immediately tried to use 'enter' and was confused when it didn't work.

Comment: Is for iPhone. You have given me an idea though, I could add to my `next 30 days`, `next 3 months`, `next 6 month` preset ranges and add date range e.g. `01-jan-2011 to 01-feb-2011`. But its going to require a lot of code, to analyse past or present dates and storing them. Hmmm

Comment: How about a pop-up dialogue with a start date and end date that will update the screen they are on (and those quick next 30 days, next 3 months and next 6 months buttons sounds like a good idea)

Comment: I have that already, the quick dates are in a popup combo, if i could add other date ranges to that too, would be great.